# Not able to Autowire ExceptionListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I have a created a `MessageListener` which will consume message from Azure service bus. While creating connection using `SingleConnectionFactory` I am trying to set a `ExceptionListener`. Both my `ExceptionListener` and Configuration are in Different classes. So in my Configuration class I am trying to Autowire a class which implements `ExceptionListener`. When I do this I am getting Autowired `ExceptionListener` as null. Please let me know whether I can autowire `ExceptionListener` or not. Please find below my sample code:

```
@Component
public class JMSExcepListener implements ExceptionListener{
@Autowired
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;

@Autowired
private SingleConnectionFactory conFactory;

@Override
public void onException(JMSException exception) {
    listenerContainer.destroy();
    listenerContainer.initialize();
    try {
        conFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Exception");
}}
```

and I am registering this listener in `SingleConnectionFactory`

```
@Configuration
public class AzureConfig{
@Autowired
    JMSExcepListener  jmsExcListener;
@Autowired
MessageConsumer messageConsumer;
    @Bean
    public SingleConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        SingleConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = null;
        try {
            cachingConnectionFactory = new SingleConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactoryImpl.createFromURL(url));
            cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setClientId(applicationName);
            singConnFactory.setExceptionListener(jmsExcListener);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
    }
 @Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer getContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new  DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    container.setDestinationName(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(messageConsumer);
    return container;
}
}
```

Here `jmsExcListener` is coming as null, but message consumer is working fine Please help.

Is it because of any circular injection, because i am trying to inject ExcepitonListener in AzureConfig and trying to inject beans created in AzureConfig into ExceptionListener. How to resolve this?

Comment: make sure your `JmsExcListener` is on component scan path and that the component scan is enabled

Comment: @borowis Component Scan is Enabled and I am able to Autowire an another component located in same package path

Comment: then it means your AzureConfig is not managed by spring, correct?

Comment: @borowis AzureConfig is managed by Spring only. Updated the code, i am able to autowire other components but ExceptionListener alone is coming as null

Comment: well, there's nothing special in this ExceptionListener, you should be able to autowire it of course, but I can't tell what's the reason from the snippet above. Maybe you could provide more code?

Comment: Where is Spring being informed about the JmsExcListener bean? You're autowiring it, but I don't see a configuration method for it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you never noticed this; you have a cyclic dependency chain.

The JMSExcepListener class requires a SingleConnectionFactory (via autowire)
which is created in the AzureConfig
bean which in turn requires a JMSExcepListener (via autowire).

The solution is always this:  Do not autowire dependencies at the class level in a configuration class.